# C#: How to cancel the focus of a previousely focused text box?

Tags: c#, focus

I have a textbox which should contain only numbers. The check is made in the Leave event. If the textbox contains characters and not numbers, it prompts the user to check their input and try again while remaining focused on the textbox.

The problem is that if the user presses cancel, the textbox still remains focused and can't click elsewhere in the form. The same happens if he deletes the contents of the textbox. What am I doing wrong? Would appreciate some help! Thanks in advance!

```
private void whateverTextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //checks to see if the text box is blank or not. if not blank the if happens
        if (whateverTextbox.Text != String.Empty)
        {
            double parsedValue;

            //checks to see if the value inside the checkbox is a number or not, if not a number the if happens
            if (!double.TryParse(whateverTextbox.Text, out parsedValue))
            {
                DialogResult reply = MessageBox.Show("Numbers only!" + "\n" + "Press ok to try again or Cancel to abort the operation", "Warning!", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

                //if the user presses ok, textbox gets erased, gets to try again
                if (reply == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    whateverTextbox.Clear();
                    whateverTextbox.Focus();
                }

                //if the user presses cancel, the input operation will be aborted
                else if (reply == DialogResult.Cancel)
                {
                    whateverTextbox.Clear();

                    //whateverTextbox.Text = String.Empty;

                    //nextTextBox.Focus();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a global variable for storing `LastControl`

Comment: I know this is the standard questionnaire when troubleshooting but here goes: Have you put a break point in the leave event and seen what happens once you exit? Are there any exceptions thrown that would halt the controls? What happens if the user hits OK? You say the same happens when the user deletes the contents of the TextBox, do they then *leave* the control, or it halts even when the TextBox remains in focus, but now the length is 0? What other events are being fired by your form and TextBox? Perhaps one of those is stuck in an infinite loop or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do something like this:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Numbers only!" + "\n" + "Press ok to try again or Cancel to abort the operation", "Warning!");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I guess I am really tired and haven't thought about it... Still, I'd like to know where the problem in the previous code was.